# multiple file upload foreach error

Tags: php, file, upload

I have used the following code several times before, and have recently found it to try and use again. There now seems to be an error which I cannot fix, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $i => $name) {     

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($name);

    if (!move_uploaded_file($file_post["tmp_name"][$i],$uploadfile)) 
    {
        echo set_e('error','Image ['.$i.'] not uploaded','');
    }


}
```

The error I get is

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /sitefolder/functions.php on line 1096
```

line 1096 is the first line in the first code box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, never use array keys without checking that they exist. Wrap you code in

```
if (array_key_exists('image', $_FILES)) 
{
  // ...
} 
else 
{
  // error handling
}
```

Second, even if the key exists, `$_FILES['image']['name']` is supposed to be a string, you cannot feed this to `foreach` anyway. Better:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
{     
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($file['name']);
  if (!move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) 
  {
      echo set_e('error','Image ['.$i.'] not uploaded','');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi tried original code, and tried it with the edit i added and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Ben: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means? A `print_r()` of `$_FILES` might also give some insight.

Comment: I mean it display the error message set_e(...). Also the print_r is returning empty ... Array()

Comment: Did you have the enctype="multipart/form-data" on the <form> tag?

Comment: I added it in after seeing the array was empty. Also change the form input elements from being an array. They're uploading now, just having to mess with the code moving it from the tmp folder. Thanks for the help